# group by independently on multiple column

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

i have  a dataframe in which i have 2 column.

```
  dataframe 1:-

  product | act
    a     |  A
    b     |  B
    c     |  C
    d     |  D
    b     |  C
    a     |  D
```

I want output like below :

```
   product   act   product_count   act_count2
     a        A       2               1
     b        B       2               1
     c        C       1               2
     d        D       1               2
```

I want separate count of each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Windowing in Pyspark

Below is the pseudo-code ( I have not run it but your code would like below)

Assuming you are working with dataframe (df)

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy('product')
w1 = Window.partitionBy('act')

df.withColumn('product_count', F.count('product').over(w)).withColumn('act_count', F.count('act').over(w1))

df.show()
```

Comment: How to make this dynamic because in my case columns are not fixed some times it has 3 column or 4 column.@ravi malhotra

Comment: you would have to store the columns in a list on which you want to group by. Then you need to write a list comprehension to generate Window.partitionBy on each column. After that, you can then write another list comprehention to apply withColumn operation using the windows created

Answer (score 1):

You can use df.select() as 
`df_count = df.select([F.count(df[col]).over(Window.partitionBy(col)).alias("{}_count".format(col)) for col in df.columns])`